# Background Center with no scroll

Tags: css

I want to place an image as a background, I've also apply the

```
background-size:cover
```

for no-scroll. The problem is when i view the page at different resolutions the whole picture (full width) showed up instead of the center portion (blue bordered area), is there any possible way that I can set the image as background with no scrolling and image will remain center aligned.[image]

this image may describe more specifically what I'm trying to ask. I just want to fix this image at any resolution but the blue bordered area must be remain center aligned,

Comment: Hii.. i don't think this is the right answer.. but i just want to tell it.. 

Why don't you give the background-image for `<body>` and then design your page as you need... won't it fulfill your need ???

Am sorry, am not so perfect in CSS... But i just wanted to know, if it won't work..

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `background-position: center center` with `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1200px; // change the width
```

and add to the background :

```
no-repeat 50% 0;
```

Comment: I'm using inline image not in the background,  <img class="background-img" src="images/bg_02.jpg" alt="">

Comment: try and change it to background image